# Write custom translation allocation in Pyramid

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, translation, pyramid

Pyramid uses gettext *.po files for translations, a very good and stable way to internationalize an application. It's one disadvantage is it cannot be changed from the app itself. I need some way to give a normal user the ability to change the translations on his own. *Django* allows changes in the file directly and after the change it restarts the whole app. I do not have that freedom, because the changes will be quite frequent.

Since I could not find any package that will help me with the task, I decided to override the **Localizer**. My idea is based on using a **Translation Domain** like *Zope* projects use and make **Localizer** search for registered domain, and if not found, back off to default translation strategy.

The problem is that I could not find a good way to place a custom translation solution into the Localizer itself. All I could think of is to reimplement the **get_localizer** method and rewrite the whole **Localizer**. But there are several things, that need to be copypasted here, such as interpolation of mappings and other tweeks related to *translation strings*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much things you have in there but I did something alike a while ago.. Will have to do it once again. The implementation is pretty simple...

If you can be sure that all calls will be handled trough _() or something alike. You can provide your own function. It will look something like it.

```
def _(val):
    val = db.translations.find({key: id, locale: request.locale_name})
    if val:
        return val['value']
    else:
        return real_gettext(val)
```

this is pretty simple... then you need to have something that will dump the database into the file...

But I guess overriding the localizer makes more sense.. I did it a long time ago and overiding the function was easier than searching in the code.

The plus side of Localiser is that it will work everywhere. Monkey patch is pretty cool but it's also pretty ugly. If I had to do it again, I'd provide my own localizer that will load from a database first and then display it's own value. The reason behind database is that if someone closes the server and the file hasn't been modified you won't see the results.

If the DB is more than needed, then Localize is good enough and you can update the file on every update. If the server will get restarted it will load the new files... You'll have to compile the catalog first.